# Polymer Template Repeat Over Multiple Charts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, polymer

I have a polymer highcharts element that works:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="bar-chart" attributes="source">
    <template>
        <div id="container" style="max-width: 600px; height: 360px;"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer("bar-chart", {
        ready: function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {type: 'bar', renderTo: this.$.container},
                title: {text:  ''},
                subtitle: {text: ''},
                xAxis: {categories: []},
                yAxis: {title: {text: ''}},
                plotOptions: {bar: {dataLabels: {enabled: true}}},
                legend: {enabled: false},
                credits: {enabled: false},
                series: [{}]
            };
            $.getJSON(this.source).done(function(chartjson) {
                options.xAxis.categories = chartjson.categories;
                options.series[0].data = chartjson.series;
                options.title.text = chartjson.title;
                options.subtitle.text = chartjson.subtitle;
                options.yAxis.title.text = chartjson.yAxistitle;
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<bar-chart source="json/grass-roots/2014 Mayor.json"></bar-chart>
```

I pass it some nice data via the '2014 Mayor.json' file:

```
{
    "categories": ["Muriel E Bowser", "Tommy Wells", "Jack Evans", "Vincent C Gray", "David Catania", "Andy Shallal", "Reta Jo Lewis", "Carol Schwartz", "Vincent Orange", "Christian Carter", "Nestor DJonkam", "Bruce Majors", "Michael L Green"],
    "series": [2505, 1654, 1332, 956, 699, 399, 183, 81, 72, 3, 3, 2, 1],
    "title": "Mayor (2014)",
    "subtitle": "Grassroots Contributors",
    "yAxistitle": "Number of DC Residents Contributing to Candidate"
}
```

And I get a chart.

But what I really want to do is iterate over an array of chart data to produce multiple charts. I've tried very hard to figure out how template repeat works, but I'm new to both Polymer and javascript, and haven't been able to crack it.

Let's say my data file, 'arrayofdata.json' has the following in it:

```
[
    {
        "categories": ["Phil Mendelson", "Kris Hammond", "John C Cheeks"], "series": [172, 44, 4], 
        "title": "Council Chairman (2014)", 
        "subtitle": "Grassroots Contributors", 
        "yAxistitle": "Number of DC Residents Contributing to Candidate" 
    },
    {
        "categories": ["Muriel E Bowser", "Tommy Wells", "Jack Evans", "Vincent C Gray", "David Catania", "Andy Shallal", "Reta Jo Lewis", "Carol Schwartz", "Vincent Orange", "Christian Carter", "Nestor DJonkam", "Bruce Majors", "Michael L Green"],
        "series": [2505, 1654, 1332, 956, 699, 399, 183, 81, 72, 3, 3, 2, 1],
        "title": "Mayor (2014)",
        "subtitle": "Grassroots Contributors",
        "yAxistitle": "Number of DC Residents Contributing to Candidate"
    }
]
```

How do I iterate over that to produce multiple charts using  template repeat?

Comment: could be of use... https://blog.polymer-project.org/howto/2014/09/11/template-is-autobinding/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a solution for Highcharts, but the Polymeric way to do this is to think declaratively. You don't need `$.getJSON`. You need an element like `<google-chart>`, that declaratively renders a chart from data and `<core-ajax>` for fetching the json data.

The whole element definition becomes something like:

```
<polymer-element name="bar-charts" attributes="source" noscript>
  <template>
    <core-ajax auto url="{{source}} response="{{items}}" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>

    <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
      <google-chart type='pie' height='300px' width='400px'
        options='{{item.options}}' cols='{{item.cols}}'
        rows='{{item.rows}}' data='{{item.data}}'>
      </google-chart>
    </template>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

How wicked is that!? No code :)

The hardest part would be to get the data in the format google-chart expects. See [`<google-chart>` element](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-chart/components/google-chart/) for examples.

Comment: This is a great point.  And, of course, massaging data into the correct form is fairly easy.  Google charts, here we come! Also, I really appreciate the sample code. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question but here's the updated **Polymeric 1.0/2.0** way of doing it, using [Highcharts-Chart](https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart):

```html
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/highcharts-chart/highcharts-chart.html">

<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{dynamicChartData}}" as="e">
    <highcharts-chart index$="[[index]]" type="pie" data="[[zip(e.categories,e.series)]]" title="[[e.title]]" subtitle="[[e.subtitle]]" y-label="[[e.yAxistitle]]"></highcharts-chart>
  </template>
  <iron-ajax auto url="{{source}}" last-response="{{dynamicChartData}}" handle-as="json"></iron-ajax>
</template>                                                   
<script>
  var app = document.querySelector("#app")
  app.source = "Your URL-------------------"
  app.zip = function(a,b) {
      return a.map(function (_, i) {return [a[i], b[i]]})
  }
</script>
```

And if you're looking for more examples you can check out http://avdaredevil.github.io/highcharts-chart/.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Polymer, but from the [docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html) it looks like changing `<template>` to `<template repeat="{{ yourarray }}">` might be the critical step in making this happen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would that it were that simple! I've tried that and various variations (nesting templates, etc.), but I haven't cracked it yet.  Rather than post my various guesses, I thought I'd post working code & ask for the next step. Hopefully one of the Polymer folk will show me the way.