# Use Metorgram HighChart in Polymer custom element

Tags: javascript, highcharts, polymer-1.0

I want to put this Meteogram High Chart inside my custom Polymer element, but with some reason i can't render the chart. Can anyone help me with this please?

My custom Polymer element:

```
<dom-module id="weather-chart">
  <template>
    <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 310px; margin: 0 auto">
      <div style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: center" id="loading">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading data from external source
      </div>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/weather-chart.js">
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The javascript code: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-meteogram/

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://github.com/gonzalopezzi/polymer_highcharts)? Or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899715/polymer-template-repeat-over-multiple-charts) ?